# Trying to take a url out of a long string

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

I have a long string of text that I've isolated from a sql table and turned into a string;

```
Thank you for your request.   
Please click the following link to reset your password:
http://localhost:5692/Public/LogonSetPassword.aspx?activationLinkId=603fa657-9460-4417-adc2-7bcad0416c3e
If clicking on the link does not work then please copy and paste it directly into your browser address bar
```

I'm now trying to just take out just the url and put that into another string. I need to grab it from "http" and end it using the space right after the unique id.

I've tried:

`string activationUrl = sql.Substring(sql.IndexOf("http", sql.IndexOf(" ")));`

However it doesn't seem to work.
Can someone explain where I'm going wrong please?
Thank you.

Comment: What does "It doesn't seem to work" mean here? What happens? What doesn't?

Comment: There is no space after your url, there's a line break. Is this *always* the case (makes the answer easy) or is there likely to be some random whitespace (like space, tab, newline etc)

Answer (score 1):

URL's can contain many characters, but they cannot contain whitespace, so you may be more successful using regex.

A simple pattern would say "Starts with http, followed by more than 1 non-whitespace character"

```
var regex = new Regex(@"http[^\s]+");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(sql));
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/BOV71354

Comment: That's not what your regex does. Your regex matches "fixed string `http`, followed by any characters, followed by **one** non-whitespace". Wouldn't `http[^\s]+` make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt, `sql.IndexOf(" ")` will match the first occurrence of a space, in your example it's at index 5 (in `Thank you`).

You have to look to the first occurrence of a new line **after** the first occurrence of `http`:

```
var startIndex = sql.IndexOf("http", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var endIndex = sql.IndexOf('\r', startIndex); // maybe '\n' or ' '
```

And `Substring` second argument is a length not an index, the correct code is:

```
var url = sql.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex - 1);
```

But the cleanest way to do this is to use [regexp](https://regex101.com/r/tqF36i/1):

```
// Assuming there is only one url and it fit alone on a single line.
var regex = new Regex(@"^http.*\r?$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var match = regex.Match(s);
if (match.Success)
{
    var url = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Index is out of range" error when I hit 'var endIndex'

Comment: @Cbear probably because `http`was not found and `startIndex` is  `-1`, with `IndexOf` you have to check all of this while the regex solution has a `Success` field.

Answer (score 0):

this solution assume that there will be only one url

```
var indexOfHttp = sql.IndexOf("http");
var strStartingFromHttp = sql.Substring(indexOfHttp);
var activationUrl = strStartingFromHttp.Substring(0 , strStartingFromHttp.IndexOf('\n'));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnUTPk

Comment: You don't even need that `strStartingFromHttp `. Both `Substring` and `IndexOf` allow for a start index argument, so you can fill `indexOfHttp` into that directly in the last line, in both the`Substring` and `IndexOf` calls.

Comment: nope , both of you are mistaken , just try this solution with your notes

Comment: @Ali Not saying it doesn't work. Just saying the middle operation is unnecessary. Replace your last line by `String activationUrl = sql.Substring(indexOfHttp, sql.IndexOf('\n', indexOfHttp) - indexOfHttp);` and you will see it never needs the `strStartingFromHttp` string. Though ideally you'd add some checks on `-1` to ensure that it doesn't crash and burn on strings that do _not_ contain a url ending on a `\n`.

Comment: @Orace Yes you do. First arg is always the _start index_. He's giving a _length_, which needs to be the _second_ argument. So the 0 is necessary.

Comment: @Ali I've tried this but I'm getting the following error "StartIndex cannot be less than zero"

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by just the url.
The code you are using is going from the first instance found of "http" in the entire text, then going to the first index of a " " in the string.
The first instance of "http" is on the third line, the first instance of " " is on the first line right after "Thank".

If the url is always going to be on a separate line, and you will only have one url, you can simply split the string by new line and check if that line starts with http:

```
string url = null;
foreach (string line in sql.Split('\n'))
{
    if (line.ToLower().StartsWith("http"))
    {
        url = line;
        break;
    }
}
if (url != null) //You found a url
```

In this case "url" will be "http://localhost:5692/Public/LogonSetPassword.aspx?activationLinkId=603fa657-9460-4417-adc2-7bcad0416c3e"

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"https?://(www.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var activationUrl = regex.Match(sql)?.Value;
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cz16QR